# dart gRPC: what the meaning of the function?

Tags: flutter, dart, grpc, syntactic-sugar

I'm new in flutter(dart) gRPC. I'm learing the tutorial given by https://grpc.io/docs/languages/dart/basics/. But I got confused about the dart syntax in this function.

```
Future<Feature> getFeature(grpc.ServiceCall call, Point request) async {
  return featuresDb.firstWhere((f) => f.location == request,
      orElse: () => Feature()..location = request);
}
```

Actually, I don't understand what argument `f` means and why there is an `orElse`. I have found `=>` means arrow function and it can be simply understood as return sentence, but I can't say I figure it out toally. Any explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`firstWhere` method takes a `Predicate`. A `Predicate` is just a function that takes in an object, and returns `true` or `false`. So basically it's saying "give me the first object from this list where *the function I'm giving you returns true*. The `orElse` is an *optional, named parameter* that says, if you've gotten to the end of the list and not a single object returned true when passed through the function I just supplied, then execute this function as a last resort and return whatever value it produces. You can think of a `Predicate` like a filter. It takes an object and returns `true` if it should pass through the filter, or `false` if it should not pass through the filter. `firstWhere` basically goes through each element checking to see if it passes through the filter, and the first time something does, it returns that element. If nothing makes it through the filter, it uses the `orElse` producer function to generate some value to return, since nothing made it through on it's own.

`(f) => f.location == request` is a function that returns true or false based on it's argument - it's a `Predicate`

`() => Feature()..location = request` is a `Producer`. A function that has no argument, but produces a value. In this case, a value that is equal to a new `Feature` with a `location` value equal to `request`. An `assignment` evaluates to the value that was assigned. The cascade `..` ensures that the `Feature` will be returned, instead of the `Point` object, `request`.

So basically you can think of it like this:
`list.giveMeTheFirstObjectWhere(thisFunctionReturnsTrue, orElse: giveMeTheValueThisFunctionProvidesIfNoneOfTheElementsReturnedTrueUsingTheOtherFunction)`

So the purpose of this code seems to be, checking if a `Feature` already exists, and if it does, it returns the first such `Feature`. If it doesn't exist, it creates a new `Feature` and returns it (however, this newly created one isn't automatically added to the list/db)

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand better.